# How do I link libxml2 with zlib1 on Windows?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, zlib, libxml2, teamspeak

I need to compile libxml2 32-bit and 64-bit binaries for my [TeamSpeak 3 plugin](https://github.com/NobleUplift/TeamSpeak3WebsitePreview) because I could not find a dll/lib 64-bit download. When I use my compiled libxml2.dll as a dependency in a command prompt application, it works just fine. However, when I try to use it as a dependency in TeamSpeak 3, the program immediately crashes on launch. Specifically it crashes on this line:

https://github.com/NobleUplift/TeamSpeak3WebsitePreview/blob/master/ts3websitepreview/plugin.c#L148

This is my batch script for compiling libxml2 on Windows:

```
@ECHO OFF
CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat"
CD libxml2-2.9.4\win32
nmake clean
cscript configure.js compiler=msvc zlib=true prefix=D:\Repos\libxml2\release include=D:\Repos\libxml2\dll\include lib=D:\Repos\libxml2\dll\bin debug=yes
nmake
nmake install
cd ../..
```

[image: working libxml2.dll is on the left, broken libxml2 is on the right]

The downloaded libxml2.dll on the left works. Compiled libxml2.dll is on the right. I've tried using the zlib flag, and I put my zlib headers in the include directory and the dll/lib in the lib directory, but I can't get it to link in the DLL.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I dunno whats wrong with yours, but here's how we compile the release version:

```
set TARGET_DIR=.\release_vc100
cscript configure.js compiler=msvc cruntime=/MD debug=no iconv=no legacy=no vcmanifest=no prefix=%TARGET_DIR% || exit /B 1
nmake /f Makefile.msvc clean || exit /B 1
nmake /f Makefile.msvc MSVC_VERSION=vc100 || exit /B 1
nmake /f Makefile.msvc install || exit /B 1
```

I guess you don't want `iconv=no`, but I'll note I explicitly specify `/MD` for the dynamic link release msvcrt and `debug=no` as well as passing `MSVC_VERSION=vc100` to the make step.

I also note you pass `zlib=true`when the options seem to take `yes|no` - and I *do* think 'true' will not interpeted as 1, but as 0. (!= `yes`)

Looking at your depwalker output again, I somehow suspect your missing `MSVC_VERSION` switch *may* actuall be a problem, because depwalker lists a missing `LIBiconv.dll` and that naming scheme (LIB prefix for dynamic object) is a *nix thing as far as I understand this.)

As for your erro line -- dll load failed -- both depwalker screenshots show missing dependency DLL files:

- Left side: iconv.dll *and* zlib1.dll are muissing
- Right side: LIBiconv.dll is missing. (But I *think* there is no libiconv.dll on Windows, so there must be some wrong linker settings (??).

---

I also pass the makefile explicitly, but that may just 
be a leftover from a prior version where we tried some customized makefiles.

Side note: Debug version as:

```
cscript configure.js compiler=msvc cruntime=/MDd debug=yes iconv=no legacy=no vcmanifest=no prefix=%TARGET_DIR% || exit /B 1
```

Comment: Wanted to work on this this weekend but instead I got wrapped up in a corrupted Git repository. Hopefully I can get back to this later in the week. Looked at my to-dos in Wunderlist and realized I've been working on just building my plugin's dependencies since April :\